# Record audio & video in browser

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hi i need to record audio and video content on frontend that is streamed to the browser from server
I've found some info about [MediaStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) so i did it and it seems that i don't record my html video and audio output **but a camera output**

```html
<audio id="audio" autoplay="true"></audio>
<video id="video" autoplay="true" playsinline="true" controls></video>
```

```js
  var constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: true,
    };


navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
            let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
            let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
            let vidSave = document.getElementById('vid2');
            let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
            let chunks = [];
            
            start.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
                mediaRecorder.start();
                console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            })
            stop.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            });
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
                chunks.push(ev.data);
            }
            mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
                let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
                chunks = [];
                let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                vidSave.src = videoURL;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) { 
            console.log(err.name, err.message); 
        });
}
```

any help is appreciated because i want to do this in clean way but for now only option i see is to record whole browser window

Comment: my fault edit was made

Comment: also there are some missing html elements that I had to fill in in my working test

Comment: So you are trying to record a video that is already recorded and exists on your website?

Comment: nah I'm streaming live video and audio to the website and i wanna record that on front end

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think that mediaStream is what your looking for

Comment: that is what I thought and i'm already writing scuffed version for recording whole browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231948/discussion-between-other-me-and-newdev2000).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm guessing you're aiming for a webcam-like setup, so this works, **on a server**, keep in mind, **you can't download video/audio unless you're hosting HTML through a server**. It won't work while testing on a file though:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
            }

            svg:not(:root) {
              display: block;
            }

            .playable-code {
              background-color: #f4f7f8;
              border: none;
              border-left: 6px solid #558abb;
              border-width: medium medium medium 6px;
              color: #4d4e53;
              height: 100px;
              width: 90%;
              padding: 10px 10px 0;
            }

            .playable-canvas {
              border: 1px solid #4d4e53;
              border-radius: 2px;
            }

            .playable-buttons {
              text-align: right;
              width: 90%;
              padding: 5px 10px 5px 26px;
            }
        </style>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
  font: 14px "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

video {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.bottom {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
        </style>
        
        <title>Recording a media element - Example - code sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <p>Click the "Start" button to begin video recording for a few seconds. You can stop
   the video by clicking the creatively-named "Stop" button. The "Download"
   button will download the received data (although it's in a raw, unwrapped form
   that isn't very useful).
</p>
<br>

<div class="left">
  <div id="startButton" class="button">
    Start
  </div>
  <h2>Preview</h2>
  <video id="preview" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div id="stopButton" class="button">
    Stop
  </div>
  <h2>Recording</h2>
  <video id="recording" width="160" height="120" controls></video>
  <a id="downloadButton" class="button">
    Download
  </a>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</div>
        
        
            <script>
                let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
let recording = document.getElementById("recording");
let startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
let logElement = document.getElementById("log");

let recordingTimeMS = 5000;

function log(msg) {
  logElement.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
}

function wait(delayInMS) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
}

function startRecording(stream, lengthInMS) {
  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  let data = [];

  recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
  recorder.start();
  log(recorder.state + " for " + (lengthInMS/1000) + " seconds...");

  let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    recorder.onstop = resolve;
    recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
  });

  let recorded = wait(lengthInMS).then(
    () => recorder.state == "recording" && recorder.stop()
  );

  return Promise.all([
    stopped,
    recorded
  ])
  .then(() => data);
}

function stop(stream) {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}

startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => {
    preview.srcObject = stream;
    downloadButton.href = stream;
    preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
    return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
  }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
  .then (recordedChunks => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
    recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
    downloadButton.href = recording.src;
    downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";

    log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
        recordedBlob.type + " media.");
  })
  .catch(log);
}, false);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stop(preview.srcObject);
}, false);
            </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

This will work if you're hosting on a server, like I said, so assuming you are, this is your code. If you haven't setup a server yet, consider using [Python](https://python.org/) and [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/), my personal favourites.

The above code is from MDN Web Docs by the way. This is where you can find the full tutorial and code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element.

Thanks and I hope this helps you, if not, please let me know!